# Can't change element class on click

Tags: jquery

Tell me please why div with id `AudioVol+..(ex.1,2,3 and other)`
dont change class name when click on element with class name `option_audio_player_mute`?

Also tell me, can I reduce/refactor my code?

```
$('.option_audio_player_mute').live('click', function () {
    var idn = this.id.split('+')[1];
    var vol1 = $('#AudioVol1+' + idn);
    if ($(this).hasClass('audio_mute')) {
        vol1.removeClass('audio_vol_not_active').addClass('audio_vol_active');
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('audio_not_mute')) {
        vol1.removeClass('audio_vol_active').addClass('audio_vol_not_active');
    }
});
```

why doesn't this work?

Comment: can you also show us the HTML part? BTW, `.live()` is deprecated on `1.8.x` you need to use `.on()`

Comment: Try to avoid the use of `+`, use `_` as you don't need to escape them when writing javascript.

Comment: also its good to cache the jquery object `$(this)` in a local variable which wud improve performance on complex pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` sign has a special meaning in CSS (and jQuery) selectors: it is used to specify [adjacent sibling selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors).

Try escaping the `+` sign in your id selector with two backslashes:

```
var vol1 = $("#AudioVol1\\+" + idn);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [.toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/), and use `.on` instead of `.live`.

```
$(document).on('click', '.option_audio_player_mute', function() {
    var vol1 = $("#AudioVol1\\+" + this.id.split('+')[1]), 
        $this = $(this);
    vol1.toggleClass('audio_vol_active', $this.hasClass('audio_mute'))
        .toggleClass('audio_vol_not_active', $this.hasClass('audio_not_mute'));
});
```